# Quicksort a 2D strings array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, quicksort

I am using quick sort algorithm to sort the strings in a 2D array. It works for most of the case but I don't know why the code doesn't work for this case. I had look through many similar questions about quick sort in SO but I still can't figure out what is the problem.

Expected output:

```
Apple
London
Switch
Table
The
```

Actual Output:

```
Apple
London
Table
Switch
The
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void quickSort(char arr[][20], int left, int right);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char str[][20] = { "Table", "Apple", "The", "Switch", "London"};

    printf("Before:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    quickSort(str, 0, 4);

    printf("After sort:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void quickSort(char arr[][20], int left, int right)
{
    int i, j;
    char *x;
    char tmp[20];

    i = left;
    j = right;
    x = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2];

    while(i <= j)
    {
        while((strcmp(arr[i],x) < 0) && (i <= right) && (j > i)) {
            i++;
        }
        while((strcmp(arr[j],x) > 0) && (j >= left) && (j >= i)) {
            j--;
        }
        if(i <= j) {
            strcpy(tmp, arr[i]);
            strcpy(arr[i], arr[j]);
            strcpy(arr[j], tmp);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if(left < j) {
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    }
    if(i < right) {
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)? It would save you some time.

Comment: This line from your implementation `x = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2];` looks weird. You only keep a pointer to a string while later you copy the strings. And I cannot remember seeing a line like that in common implementations... Looks like you should rewrite yours...

Comment: @anastaciu I dont know anything about qsort, but thanks for your suggestion. I will try to use it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I used ```x = arr[(left + right) / 2];``` at first, but then I found some codes using this instead

Comment: Hmm... I am more used of seeing `(left + right) / 2` in merge sort implementations, not on quick sort ones. Could you have mixed both?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I thought I was just picking the median element as my pivot?

Comment: The middle element `x` is your pivot, right? When you swap elements, you copy the contents of the strings. That means that the contents of `x` may change during sorting.

Comment: @MOehm yes, but ```x``` is update after swapping as the condition of my outer while loop is same as the condition of my inner if loop

Comment: Not in the code you posted.

Comment: @yuncf: what we mean is that if you want to use the median as a pivot, you should `strcpy` it to make sure that the pointed data is not altered.

Comment: @MOehm I thought I did it, thanks for your help

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am so sorry but can you please explain in more detail? I think I understood what you mean, the ```x``` might change after the swapping right? How if I update my x for each iteration? eg: put ```x = arr[(left + right) / 2];``` inside the outer while loop.

Comment: That doesn't help. It's not `x` that changes, but what `x` holds. To use a somewhat silly image: You have five cups with different drinks. When you sort them (by colour, say), you don't swap the cups, but you pour the apple juice into a spare glass, then pour the Coke into the first cup, then the apple juice into the cup where the Coke was. Now the large white cup is still the same as before and still in the same place as before, but it may contain another drink. That's what you do when you swap elements by copying their contents around.

Comment: But I think that you algorithm has other problems. For example you don't ensure that the pivot is in the place between the two partitions. That's how qicksort works: You partition your array into three partitions: less than pivot, single pivot element, greater than or equal to pivot. Now you know that the pivot element is in its correct, sorted position. Recurse on the left and right partitions.

Comment: Many implementations pick a pivot, swap it into the rightmost place, do the partitioning and then swap the pivot back in its designated place. This would get rid of your "pulling the rug out under the pivot"  problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there's a qsort function in C that you can use. Just calculate the size of your array and pass the strcmp function as the 4th argument.

```
    size_t n = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
    qsort(str, n, sizeof(str[0]), (int (*)())strcmp);
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Ah, thanks.. I'm kinda new to C myself, and when I was using qsort myself, it seemed to want me to cast to Void.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. Here's the warning I seem to get. `expected 'int (*)(const void *, const void *)' but argument is of type 'int (*)(const char *, const char *)'`

Comment: Oh, no! Your solution works, I added it to the answer because I figure you probably know better than me.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why the code doesn't work for this case

Mid point incorrectly calculated:

```
x = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2]; // Oops
// This is same as
x = arr[right/2]; // Oops
```

Use

```
x = arr[left + (right - left)/2];  // Fixed
```

Avoid

```
x = arr[(left + right)/2]; // left + right may overflow
```

With any type: `left, right`, `left + (right - left)/2` does not overflow when `left <= right`.

With `int left, int right`, `left + (right - left)/2` does not overflow when values are positive.

---

Perhaps other issues too.